# Importing squares indicated through EPSG:3035 into QGIS and merge with shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge, epsg, population

I have some data on population estimates in Germany for 1km by 1km squares. (Data can be found here: https://www.destatis.de/DE/Service/EXDAT/Datensaetze/bevoelkerung-geo-mobilfunkdaten.html when you scroll down to download.) The file you get is an excel with the Gitter-ID (Grid-ID, e.g. CRS3035RES1kmN2684000E4334000), some general information, and the population estimates. If I understand it correctly, the Gitter-ID refers to a point in the EPSG:3035 georeferencing system. My question is now how I convert this point to a square in GIS that uses the normal long-lat system, given that my other data that I have uses this system.

I have done a fair amount of search for this but could not figure out how to go about this. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, Gitter-ID are CRS3035 coordinates.

To use them in QGIS, first create columns with the N & E parts of the coordinates (split column by width in Excel), and export that Excel sheet as a .csv file

[image]

Then open this .csv in QGIS (add Text Delimited Layer) with X = the E part, Y = the N part of the coordinates, and CRS 3035
[image]

From there, you get a point grid over the whole country:
[image]

You can then color the layer by a given column value, and to have clean squares select a `Square symbol` (Simple Marker), with `Size = 1000 Meters at scale`

Color by 'plausibilierung':

[image]

Symbol: 1000m square centered on the points

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Kasper! You can't believe how helpful that was! :)

Comment: You are welcome, and lucky, with two rather complete answers !

Answer (score 6):

**In Excel**,

1. Add two empty columns next to `Gitter-ID`.
2. Split `Gitter-ID` text into different column with "Data > Text to Column". Use firstly `N`, then `E` as separator/delimiter. Enter `Y` and `X` names for new columns.

   [image]
3. Save the active sheet as CSV.

**In QGIS**,

Open "Layer > Add Layer > Add delimited Text Layer" window. Choose the CSV file. As shown in the image below:

1. Specify delimiter.
2. Check "First record has field names".
3. Select X and Y column.
4. Click "Select CRS" button.
5. Type "3035" .
6. Select the CRS from the list.

[image]

Added points:

[image]

**Final Step**:

Use "Rectangles, ovals, diamonds" tool with `Shape: Rectangle`, `Width:1000` and `Height:1000` from "Processing Toolbox > Vector Geometry". The tool gives you a layer containing squares.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much to you, too! I have been struggling with this for a fair amount of time but now it seems to work. Thanks for taking the time to write this! :)